# Want to Deploy Task on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to deploy my task (which is implemented in Hive) on AWS EC2.
I just read about the AWS, I came to know that we can create our own environment on EC2.

I am completely new to AWS. So I don't know anything about it

How to create such environment there?
I also read that we can import our VM image?
But for that the connector needed for it having .ova extension. If I download it, How to install it? (having .ova extension)

All this things is possible on AWS Free instance (creating our own environment and also VM Import)

Please guide me through this if you know about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To setup an instance on Amazon EC2 you might want to go through following guide: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/GettingStartedGuide/Welcome.html

Regarding importing your own VM image, you might want to go through following link: [Amazon EC2 VM Import](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/). They do support importing images of VMWare, Hyper V etc. In the link you will see 2 options how you can import your image:

1. Command line option
2. Amazon EC2 VM Import Connector for VMware vCenter

Personally I know that using command line option has option to provide image file in format specific to your virtual machine software. You can see details of command line options at [ec2-import-instance API reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ImportInstance.html).

Importing an image is free as there is no charge for data coming in to AWS. But there is a change for storing an instance created using image import. Every service has some sort of charge associated with it like per hour charge for instance until instance is up. So those charges are applicable regardless you are importing your image or not. Please see Amazon EC2 pricing at [EC2 pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing)